# Migration Google Apps Marketplace to V2 . How to find list of existing domains in V1?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

One of the steps in the Migration of users using UpgradeAPI says the following:
"Make a list of all the domains where the old version of your app is installed"
How do I get that list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/v2/developers_guide

I think Retrieving license notifications is what you need https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/v2/developers_guide#license_notifications

Comment: Will try it out and let you know if it worked. Since our App is a "side bar Gadget" not sure if the same licensing etc works like it would work for an App

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy link to get the list of domains, with the new Apps Marketplace API Explorer:
https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list - look at the end of the page for the form to get live data.